# CSS two layer gradient effect

Tags: html, css, styles

I have CSS command

```
        .overlay-menu {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: radial-gradient(closest-side, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);}
```

but i have problem. How i can add layer for next layer?

My idea from this command add next layer where is:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 49%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
```

I wanted [circle with linear tranparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAZrp.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two gradients together.

```css
.overlay-menu {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f69d3c, #f69d3c, transparent, #f69d3c, #f69d3c), 
              radial-gradient(closest-side, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-menu"></div>
```

Comment: Yes it is solution, but i want replace orange color as transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is solution, but i want replace orange color as transparency.

My solution i am adding:

```
.overlay-menu {
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background: radial-gradient(closest-side, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
            -webkit-mask-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, center bottom, center top,
                color-stop(0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)),
                color-stop(0.15, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
                color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)),
                color-stop(0.75, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),
                color-stop(0.85, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
                color-stop(0.95, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
              }

<div class="overlay-menu"></div>
```